# How can I find the badge ID for a per-tag badge?

Tags: support, tags, badges

Say, I want to find the list of users who have a silver [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) badge .

For non-per-tag badges, you can go to the [list of badges](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges), and click on a badge name, which takes you to a list of badge awardees.

But per-tag-badges are NOT on the list; so this approach does not work.

Now, if one knows the badge ID (which I do in this case), one can construct the per-tag-badge URL yourself.

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/78/

However, I know the ID since I already have the badge and click on it from my own badge list.

**How can I find the badge ID (or link) for a per-tag-badge?**

Please note that "Look at a user who has the badge" is NOT a valid answer, as there may be zero users with the badge so far (e.g. Gold harry-potter badge has no users).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the badge has already been given to a user, look at the [tags tab on the badges page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags).

If the badge has never been awarded, it does not have a number. Numbers are allocated to tag badges when they are first awarded.

Comment: Duh. Never notices the tags tab. Now I feel like an idiot.